# Convert sgrd (SAGA GIS format) to raster or ascii or with R

Tags: raster, r, convert, saga

I need to convert a sgrd file to tif or ascii using R. I converted a big sgrd file (1.4 GB, 376521831 pixels) to ascii using the package `RSAGA`but it takes too long (approx. 45 minutes):

```
rsaga.sgrd.to.esri(in.sgrds = "path\\dem_filename", 
                 out.grids = "output_filename", 
                 out.path = "path\\foldername", 
                 format = "ascii",
                 georef = "corner", 
                 prec = 5,
                 env = work_env)
```

How could I convert sgrd format with `rgdal` or other R packages?

Comment: How big is "big" and how long is "too long"? Can you please edit your question to give the approximate size of your raster (1000 x 1000 pixels? 10,000,000 x 10,000,000 pixels?) and how long the conversion takes, or how long you waited before giving up.

Comment: I edited my question and added the size of the file and the approximate processing time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have `.sdat` file along with `.sgrd`(header) file.

```
library(raster)
x <- raster("C:\\path\\file.sdat")
writeRaster(x, filename = "C:\\path\\file.asc", format= "ascii")
```

[EDIT] - if you need only down to 5 decimal places, `round(raster(),5)` (as below) will reduce the file size, and the processing will become faster.

```
library(raster)
x <- round(raster("C:\\path\\file.sdat"), 5)
writeRaster(x, filename = "C:\\path\\file.asc", format= "ascii")
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. It only takes 17.70 minutes for converting the 1.4 GB file. Unfortunately the resulting ascii file has 4.57 GB, where as the file produced with rsaga.sgrd.to.esri has only 3.7 GB.

Comment: @yPennylane Thank you for your feed back. I noticed you have set `prec = 5` option in rsaga.sgrd.to.esri. Please see my edit to reflect it.

Answer (score 2):

In RSAGA you can also use the "GDAL: Export Raster" module in library "io_gdal". Take a look at the output of `rsaga.get.usage("io_gdal", 1, env = work_env)`, and then use the `rsaga.geoprocessor` to call this module. This might be faster than the `rsaga.sgrd.to.esri` call.